# Use typescript with Babel 7 Standalone

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I would like to use babel-standalone (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html) with typescript.

I tried:

```
const output = Babel.transform(input, { presets: ['typescript'] }).code;
```

And:

```
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="typescript">
```

But nothing seems to work

I'm loading Babel in my app using: https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js

Comment: Find a solution?

Comment: ran into same issue, pls let me know if there's solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have only tested this with embedded javascript v8 in a C++ project. In order to transpile typescript with Babel standalone, a filename must be specified in the settings passed to `Babel.transform`, otherwise a javascript error is thrown from Babel about the missing filename.

```
const output = Babel.transform(
    input,
    {
        "presets": ["typescript"],
        "filename": "example.ts"
    }
).code;
```

The filename doesn't have to refer to a real file. However the file extension must be `.ts` for the typescript transpiler to be used.

Comment: Adding more details and context on how to use this would help more people.

Comment: I don't know what more details to add here. The only difference in my example is that I added a filename parameter (just the name, the file doesn't need to exist).